# Binary Tree problems

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

Ok, i have this binary tree, the way i wrote it the equation is outside the tree, it works but i need to know how to store the equation in the tree and calculate using the traverse function... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var node = {
  value: 125,
  left: null,
  right: null,
};

function BinarySearchTree() {
  this._root = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype = {

  constructor: BinarySearchTree,

  add: function(value) {

    var node = {
        value: value,
        left: null,
        right: null
      },
      current;

    if (this._root === null) {
      this._root = node;
    } else {
      current = this._root;
      while (true) {
        if (value < current.value) {
          if (current.left === null) {
            current.left = node;
            break;
          } else {
            current = current.left;
          }

        } else if (value > current.value) {
          if (current.right === null) {
            current.right = node;
            break;
          } else {
            current = current.right;
          }
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  },

  traverse: function(process) {

    function postOrder(node) {
      if (node) {

        if (node.left !== null) {
          postOrder(node.left);
        }

        if (node.right !== null) {
          postOrder(node.right);
        }

        process.call(this, node);
      }
    }

    postOrder(this._root);
  },

  toArray: function() {
    var result = [];

    this.traverse(function(node) {
      result.push(node.value);
    });
    return result;
  },

  toString: function() {
    return this.toArray().toString();
  }
};

function calculate(element) {
  var x = document.getElementById("xvalue").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("yvalue").value;
  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  y = parseInt(y, 10);

  var answer = 3 * (x + 5 * y);

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "3 * (x + 5 * y) = " + answer;
}
```

```html
X:
<input type="text" name="x" id="xvalue" value="1"> Y:
<input type="text" name="y" id="yvalue" value="1">
<input type="button" id="b1" value="Click Here" onclick="calculate(this)" />
<p id="output"></p>
```